# How do you distribute a Clojure program to non-programmers?

Tags: clojure

I'm new to Clojure but I'm learning it. I'd like to know the best way to package and distribute a Clojure program to end users who aren't necessarily programmers. I know in Ruby you can just tell users to download the program with `gem install [program name]` and then run the command that runs the program. What's the equivalent for Clojure programs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I you use [Leiningen](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen) it has an `uberjar` command to make self contained executable jar files, which your users can just double click.  See: http://zef.me/2470/building-clojure-projects-with-leiningen

Comment: While lein uberjar is great for small things, it's not feasible for larger projects, especially if including other 3rd party Java libraries.  Jars cannot (necessarily) be expanded, combined, and re-jarred safely.  The ordering is arbitrary in the case of path conflicts, manifests can be tricky (or impossible) to merge properly, etc.  By all means, start with uberjar but you may eventually grow out of it.

Comment: Depending on the technical level of your users, lein-tar may also be appropriate: https://github.com/technomancy/lein-tar though nothing beats the convenience of an uberjar if it works for your project.

Answer (score 2):

Clojars is great if you're distributing a library, but I'm not sure if that's the best option for end users.

If you're already using Maven, I believe the best option is to create a [uberjar](http://classworlds.codehaus.org/uberjar.html) containing all required classes. If you want to make it even more end user friendly, you can then create an installer from this jar using something like [IzPack](http://izpack.org). Just remember that Clojure programs are Java programs, so all distribution options for Java are valid for Clojure as well.

Answer (score 1):

lein uberjar works great for small mostly-Clojure apps, but it doesn't scale when using many Java libraries, including necessary licenses, and other such things.  If you use the Maven Clojure plugin, you could take advantage of the vast and terrifying Maven assembly plugin to build and final structure you might conceivably need.

Or you could write a Leiningen plugin to do something similar. I'm not sure if such a thing exists.

Answer (score -2):

Clojars (http://clojars.org/) is the bigger repository of Clojure libraries you can find.

It works perfectly with Leiningen projects or any other Maven based project management tool.

Comment: Clojars doesn't provide an installation/distribution for end-users mechanism as called for in the question.